# Simplifying radical expressions such as $\sqrt{80}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I am having trouble simplifying a radical expression, such as say...$\sqrt{80}$.

What I do is firstly, I do 80/2, then 80/3, then 80/4, then 80/5...etc until I find the largest number that can be squared. It's very time consuming. It feels like I am doing something wrong. Can someone show me a quicker way to do this? I didn't really pay attention during class when we did these stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the perfect squares under $80$?

$\sqrt{4}=2$, 
$\sqrt{9}=3$,
$\sqrt{16}=4$,
$\sqrt{25}=5$,
$\sqrt{36}=6$,
$\sqrt{49}=7$ and
$\sqrt{64}=8$.

What is the largest radicand by which $80$ is divisible?

That will be $16$, so $\sqrt{80}=\sqrt{16}\sqrt{5}=4\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that $\sqrt{4}=2$ and in this case $80$ is divisible by $4$ you could do the following: $$\sqrt{80}=\sqrt{4 \cdot 20}=\sqrt{4} \sqrt{20}=2 \sqrt{4 \cdot 5}=2 \sqrt{4} \sqrt{5}=2 \cdot 2 \sqrt{5}=4 \sqrt{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

For this particular problem note that: 
$$80=10\times 8$$
$$80=(5\times2)\times(2\times4)$$
$$80=(5\times2)\times(2\times2\times2)$$
$$80=5\times2^4$$
so you have,
$$\sqrt{80} =\sqrt{5\times2^4}=2^2\sqrt{5}=4\sqrt{5}$$
Generally you can try prime factorisation to get the simplest form, check out http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/radicals/simplify/simplifying.html